# find documents for given two dates, by start_date and end_date properties in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection as following:

```
{
    "_id": "5e46b70c06823f0fae9ffb09",
    "_created": "2020-02-14T18:04:44.000Z",
    "_updated": "2020-02-14T18:25:09.000Z",
    "name": "WEBSPR",
    "seasonal_prices": {
        "start_date": "2019-09-15T00:00:00.000Z",
        "prices": {
            "vehicle_group": "59dcb6a563da12197e08dbc7",
            "min_days": 0,
            "max_days": 1,
            "currency": "5a8a6820cae21503ec338b59",
            "daily_price": 0
        },
        "end_date": "2020-03-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5e46b70c06823f0fae9ffb09",
    "_created": "2020-02-14T18:04:44.000Z",
    "_updated": "2020-02-14T18:25:09.000Z",
    "name": "WEBSPR",
    "seasonal_prices": {
        "start_date": "2020-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
        "prices": {
            "vehicle_group": "59dcb6a563da12197e08dbc7",
            "min_days": 2,
            "max_days": 6,
            "currency": "5a8a6820cae21503ec338b59",
            "daily_price": 0
        },
        "end_date": "2020-03-25T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

I just want to get records between given start and end dates from form, ( like search things between two dates )

What I tried is:

```
{$match:{
            "seasonal_prices.start_date": {"$gte": isoPickupDateTime},
            "seasonal_prices.end_date": {"$lt": isoDropDateTime},
        }}
```

This is not working properly.

This is my console.log for each seasonal_prices document:

```
     start_date -  2019-09-15T00:00:00.000Z  - pickupDate -  2020-05-20T03:00:00.000Z  :::: end_date -  2020-03-20T00:00:00.000Z  - dropDate -  2020-05-25T03:00:00.000Z
     start_date -  2020-03-21T00:00:00.000Z  - pickupDate -  2020-05-20T03:00:00.000Z  :::: end_date -  2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z  - dropDate -  2020-05-25T03:00:00.000Z
     start_date -  2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z  - pickupDate -  2020-05-20T03:00:00.000Z  :::: end_date -  2020-05-20T00:00:00.000Z  - dropDate -  2020-05-25T03:00:00.000Z
     start_date -  2020-05-21T00:00:00.000Z  - pickupDate -  2020-05-20T03:00:00.000Z  :::: end_date -  2020-05-30T00:00:00.000Z  - dropDate -  2020-05-25T03:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: What is the console.log of those two variables?

Comment: Your dates are stored as `String`, but you are probably matching as `Date`

Comment: @hurricane I added logs.

Comment: @Valijon my dates are ISODate

Comment: "start_date": "2019-09-15T00:00:00.000Z" is String :D

Comment: @Valijon I checked with typeof now, it's object.

Answer (score 0):

For this example

```
start_date -  2019-09-15T00:00:00.000Z
pickupDate -  2020-05-20T03:00:00.000Z
end_date -  2020-03-20T00:00:00.000Z
dropDate -  2020-05-25T03:00:00.000Z
```

As you can see your query logic doesn't work.

```
start_date >= pickupDate && end_date < dropDate 
(2019-09-15 >= 2020-05-20) && (2020-03-20 < 2020-05-25)
false && true => false
```

So probably you need to use `start_date <= pickupDate && end_date < dropDate`

So in your mongo query, you can use

```
{
  "seasonal_prices.start_date": {"$lte": isoPickupDateTime},
  "seasonal_prices.end_date": {"$lt": isoDropDateTime},
}
```